# Validate user input as an integer in my guessing game

Tags: python

I have a guessing game that I want to validate the user input as a digit and the digit must be between my range(if that's even the right term here), if not then return an error message that that allows the user to try again.

I had my guessing game set up already but now I'm trying to set limits on it.
I tried using a isdigit(str) but I'm not sure I fully understand how it works so I'm kind of stuck now trying to get it to work with the TRY and Except: 
I also think I messed something up with my code that was working before because now when I input 5 for instance it says the number is not between 1 and 10 so my else statement is wrong.

```
import random

`enter code here`#Welcome Message
print("Welcome to my Guess the number program!")
print()

guess = ()
number = random.randint(1, 10)
count = 0

#User input/game rules
while True:
    guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: "))
    try:
        guess = int(guess)
        if guess<1 or guess>10:
            count += 1
            guess = int(guess)
            print()
            if guess < number:
                print("Too low.")
                print()
            elif guess > number:
                print("Too high.")
                print()
            else:
                print("You guessed it!")
                print("You guessed it in" ,count, "attempts.")
        else:
            print("number not between 1 and 10")
    except:
        print("Invalid input")[enter image description here][1]
```

***this is the code before I started messing with it.***

```
import random

#Welcome Message
print("Welcome to my Guess the number program!")
print()

guess = ()
number = random.randint(1, 10)
count = 0

#User input/game rules
while guess != number:
    guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: "))
    count += 1
    print()
    if guess < number:
        print("Too low.")
        print()
    elif guess > number:
        print("Too high.")
        print()
    elif guess == number:
        print("You guessed it!")
        print("You guessed it in" ,count, "attempts.")
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

```
if guess<1 or guess>10:
```

When guess is `5` then it is `False` and it goes to

```
else:
   print("number not between 1 and 10")
```

You need

```
if guess>=1 and guess=<10:
```

or shorter

```
if 1 <= guess =< 10:
```

---

You use `int()` in three places

```
guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: "))
try:
    guess = int(guess)
    if guess<1 or guess>10:
        count += 1
        guess = int(guess)
```

but you could do it only once.

And you should do it inside `try/except`

```
guess = input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: ")
try:
    guess = int(guess)
    if 1 <= guess =< 10:
        count += 1
```

Comment: Will that make it so if they enter a letter for example that it will be invalid also?

Comment: when user put invalid value (ie. `Hello World`,`1.25`, `$5`) then`int()` will generate exception `ValueError` and `try/except` will catch it and run `print("Invalid input")` . This is why `int()` has to be inside `try/except`.

Answer (score 0):

comments on your code:

1. put your "input statement" inside try...except.
2. use int() one time only
3. if logic is not correct
4. count variable should be one not zero
5. repeating empty print() if you put it to print extra new line you can add '\n' to previous print statement

see below mods on your code it works:

```
import random
#Welcome Message
print("Welcome to my Guess the number program!\n")
number = random.randint(1, 10)
count = 1

while True:
    try:
        guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: "))
        if guess>=1 and guess<=10:
            count += 1
            if guess < number:
                print("Too low.")
            elif guess > number:
                print("Too high.")
            else:
                print("You guessed it!")
                print("You guessed it in" ,count, "attempts.")
        else:
            print("number not between 1 and 10")
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
```